# Getting QFS for Solaris 10

Tags: filesystems, solaris, storage, sun

I am trying to get the QFS FS which comes along with SUN Storage solutions,

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/storage/storage-software/031712.htm

But the download link on that page leads to sun.com And i am getting redirected from there back to oracle's standard page.

Any idea how to get the package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it here: http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=4429b168

Source is available here: http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+samqfs/sourcecode